# specify minimum height divs to stop footer div crashing body divs

Tags: css, height, minimum

This is so simple I'm sure, but I'm stumped.

I have a footer on a webpage, and all I want to do is make sure that it is always a fixed height from the bottom, BUT specify a minimum height for the page, so that it never crashes over content divs, and instead scrolls.

Any ideas?

Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/vF4L3/

```
<div class="height">
square box
</div>

<div class="height2">
horozontal box
</div>

.height {
    background-color: hsla(121,90%,48%,1);
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    top: 50px;
}
.height2 {
    background-color: hsla(359,90%,48%,1);
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `position: fixed`?

Comment: no specifics Adam, I have been fiddling for a few hours, and that was my last position that's all. Any better suggestions?

Comment: `position: fixed` takes an element completely out of the document flow so any other elements around it "pretend" that it's not even there (similar to `position: absolute`) That's probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I use to lock my footer, I hope this helps you.

```
.Footer 
{
    clear: both;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    background: #4b6c9e;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* stick to bottom */
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}

<div id="Footer" class="Footer ui-corner-all">
<span style="float: left; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px">
</span>
<span id="clock" style="float: right; vertical-align: middle; padding: 5px">
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but not quite it, as I can still crash the content above. I'll keep looking

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this perhaps...?

#### http://jsfiddle.net/vF4L3/3/

```
.body {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-150px;
    padding-bottom:150px;
    background:#CCC;    
}

.footer {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    height:100px;
    width: 100%;
    background:#C00;
}
```

What do you mean by "crash the content"? **If you could elaborate more on this I'm sure I can help.**